# Sharepoint Designer 2010 - Workflow Send Email to "BCC" without "To" field

Tags: email, workflow, sharepoint-designer

As shown [here](http://www.tcscblog.com/2010/11/30/add-bcc-recipient-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow-e-mails/) I can set the BCC field in mail sending operation in sharepoint designer 2010 for the workflow.

But when I try to publish it without the "To" field but only with "BCC"; it gives me the publishing is failed error due to the compilation errors. When I set a dummy "To" field, then it is ok to publish and succeeds.

Any idea about if I can make it without setting "To" field.

Comment: I reckon this may be a case of setting the to: field to xxx@example.org.  Not a satisfactory solution, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it won't be possible. Sending an email, without a To field, is a red flag for many email servers and spam filters. I suggest using a generic account, or use a fake account for the sake of sending.

Comment: Yep, we've registered a dummy email account for that. thanks.